# CSRF _token value refresh in a login form

Tags: ajax, session, laravel, csrf, laravel-5

I have a login form submitted with Ajax. In one specific case, after the user logs in, I need to log them out with `Auth::logout()` and display an additional modal box. All of this happens with no page reload.

When the login modal is opened and submitted again, I get a **Token mismatch error**. The reason why this happens is because the logout uses `Session::flush()`. After this the `_token` Session variable is refreshed, while the `_token` input in the login form stays the same (because of the mentioned lack of page reload).

How can I refresh the CSRF `_token` in the login form, so it matches the one refreshed in the Session in a secure way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your login is submitted via ajax, your server is presumably sending back some kind of response to let the browser know the login was successful. You should send back the new CSRF token with this response, so that you can update the form client-side (with javascript).

To provide any more detail (how to update form fields, for example) we would need to see more of your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I ended up doing as you wrote: I pass the new token as an extra property to my JS script and update the `_token` input value. Seems to be enough.